# what is 'alpha' and 'alphadash'

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I recently encountered a part of PHP code right below:

```
$this->validate($request, [
   'name1'=>'required|alpha|unique:users',
   'name2'=>'required|alphadash'
]);
```

the question what is 'alpha' and 'alphadash' and what happens when I using them in middle of my coding?

Comment: See: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#available-validation-rules

Comment: what's this `'->'` this part `what happens when I` I think it will blow up with a parse error.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix yes I know it is just a typo, tnx

Comment: No problem, don't want someone to get distracted by typo's....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**alpha:**

The field under validation must be entirely alphabetic characters.

Please folow this [link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#rule-alpha) for more details about alpha

**alpha_dash:**

The field under validation may have alpha-numeric characters, as well as dashes and underscores.

Please follow this [link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#rule-alpha-dash) for more details about alpha_dash

Answer (score 0):

**Alpha:**

This matches any Unicode character that is a letter, or a combining mark in some languages.

**Alphadash:**

This will only accept alpha-numeric, underscores and dashes.

Comment: ... and underscores.